# Activator.CreateInstance(t, 42, args) cannot find constructor

Tags: c#, .net, types, activator, createinstance

I am using (a slightly extended version of) the following code in a factory-pattern style function:

public class SingleItemNew : CheckoutContext
   {
      public BookingContext Data { get; set; }
      public SingleItemNew(BookingContext data)
      {
        Data = data;
      }
   }
public CheckoutContext findContext(BookingContext data)
{
Type contextType = Type.GetType("CheckoutProcesses." + data.Case.ToString());
         CheckoutContext output =
            Activator.CreateInstance(contextType, BindingFlags.CreateInstance, new[] { data }) as CheckoutContext;
return output;
}

however, it throws a constuctor not found exception when run, and I cannot figure out why.

The data.Case.ToString() method returns the name of a class, SingleItemNew, that has a constructor taking a single argument.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Cheers, Ed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this one:

```
  Type contextType = Type.GetType("CheckoutProcesses." + data.Case.ToString());
  CheckoutContext output = 
      (CheckoutContext)Activator.CreateInstance(contextType, data);
```

The reason you code doesn't work is that `Activator.CreateInstance` doesn't really have the overload you want. So you might wonder why the code compiles at all! The reason is, it has an overload that takes `(Type type, params object[] args)` which matches your method call so it compiles but at runtime, it searches your type for a constructor taking a `BindingFlags` and a `BookingContext[]` which is clearly not what your type has.

Comment: spot on, I obviously shouldn't read the doc pages for classes, they lie! (The doc for Activator.CreateInstance tells you to use (type, object[] params) to call the constructor with the relevant number of arguments inside params!) =D

Comment: It doesn't lie. Did it tell you to specify the BindingFlags unless you really need it? ;)

Comment: Nope, but it didn't work without either! (I've been hacking away at this for a good while now) =D

Comment: By the way, you can always right click on the method name in code and use `Go to definition` to see which overload is resolved.

Comment: Activator.CreateInstance must have one of the most confusing set of overloads in the entire .NET Framework!

Comment: It would definitely make me think twice before using a paramarray in any overloaded methods.

Answer (score 1):

Is the constructor public?

Is the single parameter of type `BookingContext`?

The trouble is, this is clearly part of a bigger system - it would be *much* easier to help you if you could produce a [short but complete program](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/complete.html) which demonstrated the problem. Then we could fix the problem in that program, and you could port your fix back to your real system. Otherwisewise we're really just guessing :(

Answer (score 0):

Does the SingleItemNew constructor take BookingContext as parameter? If it does not match exatcly it will fail:

```
class ParamType   {    }
class DerivedParamType : ParamType    {    }
class TypeToCreate
{
    public TypeToCreate(DerivedParamType data)
    {
        // do something
    }
}

ParamType args = new ParamType();
// this call will fail: "constructor not found"
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeToCreate), new object[] { args });

// this call would work, since the input type matches the constructor
DerivedParamType args = new DerivedParamType();
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypeToCreate), new object[] { args });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Type.GetType("namespace.class, namespace");